# Inputting data from a text file with multiple numbers on each line - Python

Tags: python, input

Lets say I have a data file that has this inside it:

```
23 33 45
91 81 414
28 0 4 
7 9 14
8 9 17
1 1 3
38 19 84
```

How can I import it into a list so that each individual number it its own item?

Comment: At least specify exactly what output format you want, one long list, as list of list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could alternatively use the python builtin functions like open file, split and readlines

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
for line in f:
  a, b, c = map(int, line.split())
```

Another approach is

```
 file                = open(filename)
 file_data           = file.readlines()
```

But, the output will be a list of strings.
That is the each element in the list will represent one line in the file.
If you use the above code the output will look like

```
 file_data = ['23 33 45', '91 81 414', '28 0 4 ', '7 9 14', '8 9 17', '1 1 3', '38 19 84']
```

You might want them to convert to either float or int.
you could do that using again numpy's fromstring module

```
  from numpy import fromstring
  data = [fromstring(i, dtype=float, sep=' ') for i in file_data ]
```

Notice that, I have used a list comprehension in the above code(which is faster than the conventional python for loop.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use, numpy loadtxt to read the data file to a numpy array

```
  from numpy import loadtxt
  a,b,c = loadtxt("filename", usecols=(0,1,2), unpack=True)
```

Output

```
  a = array([23, 91, 28, 7, 8, 1, 38])
```

Comment: No need of `numpy` here. Also as `numpy` is not a built-in module, we better not use it in this case.